# store associative array into single line for sql update

Tags: php

I want to take an associative array and parse that to put into the `SET` part of an `UPDATE` query:

My call with the associative array:

```
$this->ccQuery( 'emails', array('user_id' => $id, 'email_address' => $request->email) );

function ccQuery( $t, $a, $id=null )
{
        foreach($a as $key=>$value)
        {
            $setfields[] = $key . "='" . $value . "'";
        } 
        $setfields = implode(', ', $setfields);


        $testquery2 = 'UPDATE mytable_'.$t.' SET ' .$setfields. ' WHERE user_id="'.$user_id;
...
}
```

`setfields` is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well, the obvious question is where does `$array` come from in your loop since it isn't defined, maybe you meant `$a`

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the loop, so setfields should be a string, however `$user_id` is not defined which you're attempting to use in your query

Comment: ah whoops I was looking at the wrong thing. Your right. Duh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
...

$testquery2 = "UPDATE mytable_"


foreach($a as $key=>$value)
        {
           $testquery2 = $testquery2 ."$t SET '$value' WHERE user_id= '$id'";
        } 

...
```